# apt-get to install a package and its first level dependencies only?

Tags: apt, dependencies, ros

Is there a way I can use apt-get install command to install a package and its first level dependencies only instead of all the dependencies recursively?

EDIT: 
I am dealing with ROS and would like to install a single package with only its first level dependencies. I don't actually want to install or update the system dependencies that this ROS package depends on, "recursively". During running a particular application if any 'dependency-not found' error is thrown, I would like to see what exactly is missing. I hope this helps. 
PS: Also, it seems that there is an apt-get command to install only the first-level dependencies but couldn't find any. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible. "First-level" dependencies will not install without there own dependencies. It will be much better if you ask about a real problem.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: "it seems that there is an apt-get command to install only the first-level dependencies" Why do you think that?

Comment: @muru my mentor said so and asked me to look for the command.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no way to use `apt-get` and install packages without fulfilling dependencies. You can download the individual packages and use `dpkg`, but the packages will not be fully installed in that case, and programs may not even be startable.

Comment: I found a command `debtree --max-depth=number` that limits the traversal of dependency depth. Is there a way I can integrate this with `apt-get install` to serve my purpose? something like `debtree --max-depth=1|sudo apt-get install` ?

Comment: No. Use `dpkg` if you want to ignore dependencies.

Comment: Could you please tell how exactly I can use it. and also, when installing individual dependencies (top-level) using `dpkg`, won't their dependencies also get installed?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/40781/158442 `dpkg` doesn't download or install anything other than what it has been told to.